# Dart List and PhP

Tags: php, dart

I wanna put the data that I received with php into List that i have in dart class.
To recieve and show data i use

```
    <?php 
    $contador=1; 
do { ?> 
Latitud:<?php echo $row['latitud']; ?><br /> 
Longitud:<?php echo $row['longitud']; ?><br />
calle: <?php echo $row['calle']; ?><br />
-----------------------------------------------<br />
<?php  
$contador++;} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cplusplus)); ?>
```

but i dont know how i can put this data into List.
My idea is that i create a object and i give it 2 parameters String Latitud and  String Longitud.
Later I put this object into List.

```
    class Timeline {
  String latitud;
  String longitud;
  List todas_localizaciones=new List();

  void add()
  {
    Localizaciones nuevo=new Localizaciones(latitud,longitud);
    todas_localizaciones.add(nuevo);

  }
}
```

Object

```
    class Localizaciones
{
  String latitud;
  String longitud;

  Localizaciones(String la,String lon)
  {
    latitud=la;
    longitud=lon;
  }
}
```

thanks you!

Comment: I will assume you should export it from PHP into JSON (maybe a .json file) and then read/parse that file with your Dart app. Another option: Make PHP behave like a web service by having it return JSON when called from your Dart app. Then parse, the JSON in Dart to your object(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first part of your question, it appears that you're trying to inline your PHP with the HTML (and assumingly) the dart script. However this won't work in the same way with Dart for a few of reasons.

1. Dart is designed to be a client-side script which manipulates the DOM among other things. Having the server-side script do similar will cause unexpected behaviour at best and totally break at worse.
2. Much of the focus of Dart is to create SPA's (or Single Page Applications). While Dart can be used outside of that context, it's much more idiomatic to create single page applications which do not require reloading the page to parse server-side changes.
3. Most importantly, normal Dart scripts are compiled (and usually minified) prior to being put into pages. This compilation completely changes the scripts interface and lines and happens before it's even uploaded to the server in most cases, not after the server has passed values into the script.

Making the move from applications which are primarily handled server side, to Dart applications which are primarily client-side takes a little bit of a mental shift in how you approach the apps. Instead of using the PHP script to render vital components of the dart scripts (such as a list), it involves loading the entire Dart script, and then using AJAX calls to query the server for any other values it may require and inserting them dynamically into the page as need be.

As a start into client-side/server-side programming with Dart I highly recommend the [Dart Tutorials](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/). In particular, the tutorial [Get Input from a Form](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/) is a great example of using AJAX requests. This sample also shows the server side programming as it would be handled in Dart, however you can quickly and easily create a PHP script on the server to handle the server-side tasks and return the values/responses.

**Hint**: Anything that is echo'd by the PHP script will be the value of the Dart's [HttpRequest.responseText](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html.HttpRequest@id_responseType). And PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) can encode an array and return a String which can be decoded by Dart's [JSON.decode](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_convert@id_JSON) method.